# Comparing a String with a template like string

Tags: java, string, stringtemplate

I am trying to write a program in which I have to do comparison between a list of strings with a template (which is essentially a string). I am not sure what is the term used but it is going to be more of log scraping program if that helps.

Input String Examples:

1. Hello World this is me
2. Hello Strange World this is a someone
3. This is a test file
4. Hello World this is a bot

To be compared against

a. This is a **?** file

b. Hello World this is **?**

The idea is to match input statements (1-4) against template strings (a-b) and if they match then I need to act on them. Like 1 & 4 match sentence ***b*** but ***2*** does not.

Thanks in advance for help/directions.

Comment: your template strings make me think that you should use regex!

Comment: In that case I might have replace ***?*** with a regex and then match it with incoming string ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `?` to `.*` and you've got a regex:

```
String input = "Hello World this is me";

if (input.matches("Hello World this is .*"))
    // true
```

etc

Comment: Sorry if I gave a bad example but I might have the ***?*** strings in middle of a sentence and I am little worried about the punctuation coming in the log statements

Comment: @Rox - You can deal with punctuation using regexes.  Read http://www.regular-expressions.info/  and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @StephenC - Thanks I think that would help. Cheers !